# Textfeild that is at the bottom is hidden under the keyboard while keyboard is up

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, keyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZUZb.png) this is the the issue

```
follwing is my bottomscreen code....
```

```
Future<dynamic> newtrasactionNavigator(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        isDismissible: false,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(25), topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return NewTransaction();
        });
  }
```

Comment: Can you show your NewTransactin Code? I guess you have a Column in this widget, try to wrap it inside a SingleChildScrollView

Comment: What is your question? Ideally ask one according to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you should add padding like this :

```
EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
```

change your code to this style:

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return  SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,),
              child: YourModalBody(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        })
```

and be careful to put this line `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in you Scaffold of your screen like this:

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
...........
);
```